# AngularJS sharing async data between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

There's quite a few topics out there covering issues with sharing data between controllers, but I havn't found any good answers for my case.

I have one controller that fetches data asynchronous using promise. The controller then makes a copy of the data to work with within that scope. I then have a second controller which I want also want to work on the same copy of data that of the first controller so they both share it.

Here's some code simplified to serve as example:

```
.controller('firstController', function ($scope, someService){
    var vm = this;
    someService.getData().then(function(data) {
        angular.copy(data, vm.data); //creates a copy and places it on scope
        someService.setCurrentData(vm.data)
    }
});

.controller('secondController', function ($scope, someService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = someService.getCurrentData(); //Triggers before the setter in firstController
});

.factory('someService', function(fetchService){
    var _currentData = {};

    var getData = function(){
        return fetchService.fetchData().then(function(data) { return data; });
    };

    var getCurrentData = function(){
        return _currentData;
    }

    var setCurrentData = function(data){
        _currentData = data;
    }
});
```

As the getData is async will the setCurrentData be triggered after the getCurrentData, so getCurrentData gives a different object and does not change to the correct one. I know you can solve this with broadcast and watch, but I'm trying to avoid using it if possible.

Comment: You should keep the async API for getCurrentData(), if _currentData isn't set, getCurrentData() should call getData().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor your factory to check if the `_currentData` variable has already been set - then you can simply use callbacks:

```
app.factory('someService', function(fetchService){
    var _currentData = null;

    var setCurrentData = function(data){
        _currentData = data;
    }

    var getData = function(callback) {
        if (_currentData == null) {
            fetchService.fetchData().success(function(data) { 
                setCurrentData(data);
                callback(data); 
            });
        } else {
            callback(_currentData);
        }
    };

    /*
    var getCurrentData = function(){
        return _currentData;
    }
    */
});
```

Now, calling your `getData` service will check if the data is already got and stored, if so, use that, else go get it!

```
someService.getData(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //yay for persistence!
})
```

Comment: Nice, but what I don't like is the callback function inside the getData. Wouldn't it be better for getData to return a promise?

Answer (score 2):

I would solve in this way:

```
.controller('firstController', function ($scope, $rootScope, someService){
    var vm = this;
    someService.getData().then(function(data) {
        angular.copy(data, vm.data); //creates a copy and places it on scope
        someService.setCurrentData(vm.data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myData:updated');
    }
});



.controller('secondController', function ($scope, $rootScope, someService){
        var vm = this;
        $rootScope.$on('myData:updated', function(event, data) {
           vm.data = someService.getCurrentData(); 
        });
});
```